# Is it a bad thing to catch System.Exception in .NET?

Tags: .net, exception

In .NET, System.Exception is the root class of all exceptions, just like the java.lang.Throwable class in Java. It seems that, many people think that, it is a bad thing to catch java.lang.Throwable in Java. So, I want to know: Is this the same for .NET? Is it a bad thing to catch System.Exception in .NET?

Comment: It's a bad idea to catch *any* exception unless you have a clear strategy for dealing with the issue and allowing your program to continue to operate sensibly. What possible strategy can you have that will work for every possible exception?

Comment: It is okay to display a friendly message to the user that describes the mishap and terminate the program.  Don't skip the terminating part, Environment.Exit() or FailFast(). 
 AppDomain.UnhandledException is in general the better way to do that.

Comment: If it is a GUI program, and it tries to do something but fails, I may want to show an error message to the user, but allow the program to continue running, instead of simply crashing (which is the consequence of not catching the exception thrown), which is obviously a bad user experience, and even worse, may leave the user no chance to save his or her data in this program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you do something useful with the exception, it isn't considered bad practice. But catching *all* exceptions without some sort of logging is quite obviously a bad practice.

```cs
// ------- GOOD -------
try
{
    // some code that might break things
} catch (Exception ex)
{
    Logger.LogException(ex, "Some code that might break things failed.");
}

// ------- BAD --------
try
{
    // some code that might break things
} catch (Exception ex) { }
```

Comment: I may want to show an error message to the user, and let the program continue running, instead of simply crashing.

Comment: @zhoudu as long as you leave _some_ feedback it's absolutely fine to do this

Comment: Yes, I also think so. It is interesting that most Java developers do not think so for the Java java.lang.Throwable class.